# UISplitViewController is not being displayed correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I created and loaded a `UISplitViewController` in an existing `ViewController` by writing the following code in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
LeftPanelViewController *leftPanel = [[LeftPanelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftPanelViewController" bundle:nil];
FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstView];

UISplitViewController *splitController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftPanel, self.navigationController, nil];

[self.view addSubview:splitController.view];
[self addChildViewController:splitController];

[splitController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Everything is fine except for the fact that the splitController is not being drawn in the borders of the iPad, there's a space between the top of the screen and the top of the view. Even when I rotate the iPad the left panel is also having the same problem.

`SplitViewController` doesn't have a xib file, and when I change the added view for another that has, everything is correctly displayed.

Any ideas of what may cause this problem?

**Notes:**
Compiling and running the project in the simulator multiple times causes the `SplitViewController` to be displayed sometimes without any problems and others with spaces between any of the edges of the screen and the view. Running in the iPad causes always the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all.. why do you implement a container view controller? I guess you just want to present the splitViewController on its own, right? Than don't add the view yourself.

Instead correctly set it as your `rootViewController` on your window (preferably in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`).

```
self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
```

Container View Controller are not needed in standard cases. So you should never need to use the following methods:

```
addChildViewController:
removeFromParentViewController
willMoveToParentViewController:
didMoveToParentViewController:
```

Check the [documentation of UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

If you really wanted to implement a Container View Controller, than you need to take care of the layout yourself. So you need to position / size the view of the other controller yourself. Depending on if you use AutoLayout or autoresizing, you need to set correct constraints/flags.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented a container view controller because when the app runs in an iPhone a slide-out navigation is used. In this case I need the container but when I was going to write the code for the iPad I just went directly and used the container I already had. Silly me